# How can i give command line arguments without using out extension ,not ./a.out 3 4 but like ./a 3 4

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, command-line

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("missing argument\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("%s %s %s", argv[1], argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Just want to give command line arguments like ./a 3 4 without using .out in linux terminal thanks!!

Comment: Just don't compile it with the .out in the name?

Comment: no it says ./a  no such file exist in the directory but if i run it with ./a.out it works fine

Comment: `gcc` accepts the `-o` flag allowing you to rename `a.out` to whatever you want.

Comment: if it's already compiled simply rename it to remove .out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your source file was `a.c`, just use the `-o` ("output") flag when you compile it, like this:

```
cc -o a a.c
```

Or, if you already did

```
cc a.c
```

meaning it left it in `a.out` by default, you can always rename it:

```
mv a.out a
```

Of course you can call it anything you want:

```
cc -o mytestprogram a.c
```